# Jersey 2.22: How do I retrieve the URL (with QueryParams) from WebTarget?

Tags: java, url, jersey

Assume that:

`WebTarget target = client.target("http://www.someurl.com");`

`target.queryParam("id", "1").request().post();`

And when a request is done on that target, how do I get the full URL which is http://www.someurl.com?id=1 using the Jersey api?

Answer (score 2):

The thing is, if you look at the javadoc for [`WebTarget`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/client/WebTarget.html), you will see that most of the method calls on `WebTarget` return a *new* `WebTarget` instance. So when you do

```
WebTarget target = client.target("http://www.someurl.com");
target.queryParam("id", "1").request().post();
System.out.println(target.getUri());
```

The `target` instance is not the same instance that the query parameter is added to. So you would need to either do

```
WebTarget target = client.target("http://www.someurl.com");
WebTarget newTarget = target.queryParam("id", "1");
newTarget.request().post();
System.out.println(newTarget.getUri());
```

Or

```
WebTarget target = client.target("http://www.someurl.com").queryParam("id", "1");
target.request().post();
System.out.println(target.getUri());
```

Comment: Yeah I did this but I didn't get the query params attached to the URL

Comment: Worked fine for me when I tested, before posting this answer

Comment: Thanks for the info. This solved my problem.
IMHO target.queryParam returning a new object is silly. I expected it to work like apache.

Comment: @jkb016 I think the purpose is for `WebTarget`s to be reusable